# How to get a JFrame position in the screen to put in a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

i was wondering if it possible to get the position of the location on the screen of a JFrame, to put the same location in a JDialog. I mean, that i want to do is when i open a JDialog from a JFrame button, i want to put the JDialog in the same position that the main JFrame, maybe with the .setLocationRelativeto() method, any ideas to do it??, thank you!.

```
   this.setUndecorated(true);
   initComponents();
   this.setBounds(WIDTH, WIDTH, 444, 308);
   JDialog dialog=new JDialog();
```

I want to adopt the same position from the mainJFrame, but i dont know how to to it....

```
   dialog.setLocationRelativeTo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to get the position of the location on the screen of a JFrame

The code in the `ActionListener` would be something like:

```
Component c = event.getComponent();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(c);
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(...);
...
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocation( window.getLocation() );
dialog.setVisible( rue ;
```

or you could center the dialog on the frame by using:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo( window );
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

EDIT For the record, `JFrame` extends `Window`, so if you already have your `JFrame`, that may be enough.